# What happens if the maximum length of archive is reached?

Tags: java, file

I'm learning java and we see the class `RandomAccessFile()` and the length of the file is a `long` type (8 bytes) and I wonder what happened if the maximum size of the file is reached, do I need to explicitly create a new one or there is a way to extend it?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about!! I believe you don't know what you are talking about either. What did you mean by "if the size of the file is reached"?

Comment: I forgot to say the maximum size thanks

Comment: 2^63 is about 10^19 or about 10,000 terabytes.

Comment: Are you aware how large that maximum size is? 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes, or 9,223,372 TB @Jim who is right, you or me? I am confused :D

Comment: oops @Sнаđошƒаӽ  is correct, I must have dropped the extra 3 zeros on the floor :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will never reach this limit (`2^63 - 1`) as it is not supported by JVM and most probably by your operating system as well, but if your operating system supports it you would simply get `IOException` with message `"Seek failed"` (see `RandomAccessFile.c` for details).

Answer (score 0):

You would run out of computer memory before you run out of file "space". You see a `long` can represent numbers up to 2^64 which is much much larger than your computer's storage capacity.

Comment: You don't need necessarily to run out of computer memory. As long as operating system AND file system support it you can create file with "holes" (look for sparse file) that won't use more memory than size of metadata.